# Get list of applicable shipping methods

Tags: 8, commerce

I would like to get the list of applicable shipping methods for the current cart but dependent on the selected shipping profile. I'm programming a custom controller that should returns the list of available shipping methods and rates but, obviously, given a cart and a customer's shipping profile.
Has [commerce shipping module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping) any service or class that could I use to get this information? Perhaps, is there any other way to get it?

I've been reading source code from:
*Commerce_Shipping\src\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\ShippingInformation.php*
That is the CheckoutPane plugin that renders shipment options in checkout page. `buildPaneForm` method renders this form, and those lines of code should give me the list of shipping methods:

```
 public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    ...
    $shipments = $this->order->get('shipments')->referencedEntities();
    ...
    foreach ($shipments as $index => $shipment) {
    ... // all shipments
    }
```

But I have tried it in my custom controller and It always returns empty array. I think there should be a prior process that populate this list, but I can't find it. I have tried appling a state transition but It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some in-depth research on commerce modules, I have found a way to get them. This is an excerpt of the source code with the main instructions (controller class that returns JSON):

```
public function getShippingMethods(Request $request, $id) {
          
    $commerce_order = Order::load($id);       
    // ... some checks to ensure it is a commerce order

    $shipments = $commerce_order->get('shipments')->referencedEntities();
    
    $options = [];
    foreach ($shipments as $shipment) {     
      assert($shipment instanceof ShipmentInterface);      
      $rates = $this->shipmentManager->calculateRates($shipment);
      foreach($rates as $rate) {
        $options[] = [ "id" => $rate->getShippingMethodId(), 
                       "method" => $rate->getService()->getLabel(), 
                       "import" => $rate->getAmount()->getNumber(),
                       "description" => $rate->getDescription()];              
      }
    }
            
    // Return JSON with all shipping methods
    return new JsonResponse( $options );
  }
```

Hope It could help someone.